# Where do I set up an MX record for my Google domain so it points to my email server?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record, digital-ocean, google-domains

I'm new to networking and servers, so I may be way off track. I have a Digital Ocean server with postfix configured on it. I also have a domain through Google Domains. I want to make it so my mail server can receive mail, so I'm setting up an MX record. However, both Google Domains and Digital Ocean have places in their DNS configuration where I can add a DNS record. Where should I add the record at? Thanks so much for any insights or resources.

Comment: Your domain has only one DNS provider. The `MX` record should be set at your DNS provider. Both of the companies you list should be able to help you by answering your question if you are not clear on who is your DNS provider (no one can know, since you forgot(?) to tell which domain you are talking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control who serves up DNS results for your domain by setting the Name Server (NS) records for your domain with your Domain Registrar.  You should be able to figure out who you registered your domain with by

1. Search back through your email history to see if you have some correspondence with, and see if they have a way to configure where your NS records point.
2. Either by learning the commandline tool 'nslookup' in Windows or using an online version like the one at https://nslookup.io/, see where you currently have your NS records pointing

either way - once you have a view on where your NS records point at the moment,  you can use the relevant portal to then setup the MX records you need to direct mail delivery to your mail server.

Good luck - it can seem like a bit of an arcane world at times but you seem like you're well on your way up the sometimes-steep learning curve.

Comment: My Name Server records point to Digital Ocean servers, so I must need to add the MX record on Digital Ocean. Thanks for the advice and encouragement!